# Where's the best place to get my iPad, iPhone and iPod touch questions answered?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Since iPad, iPhone and [iPod Touch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_Touch) related questions are being closed on Super User where is the best place to get answers to these questions?

Answer (score 6):

[Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) has been live for quite some time now.

Comment: boo apple site.  booo.

Comment: @quack, why boo?  Prefer to see apple users on superuser?   I'd theoretically agree, but the problem today is that it doesn't allow for the full family (the iPad/iPhone/mac combo) and it doesn't have sufficient Mac user base to answer most questions, or at least not quickly...

Comment: because i'd rather see a larger OS X community on SU, and a decent Apple-gadget community on the gadgets site when it gets up and running.  there's enough crossover between OSX and other Unixen that the OSX questions benefit SU, and there'll probably be crossover between jailbreak questions on Apple gadgets and Android on the gadgets site.  you'll lose that crosspollination on a fanboy monoculture site.

Comment: The gadgets site was turned down a long time ago. OS X questions might be asked on [su], [unix.se] and [apple.se].