# When should site-specific tags be included in site recommendation questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

There are several [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) questions, including site-specific tags; however, several questions recommend, i.e, Web Applications SE not having a tag for this site.

There are 6 questions, including [google](/questions/tagged/google). One of the questions is about the Google Maps API. In this case, the recommendation mentions [GIS Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/).

I know that tags like [stack-overflow](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow), [serverfault](/questions/tagged/serverfault) and [superuser](/questions/tagged/superuser) are from the time when there was no per-site child meta. WordPress development was launched after Web Applications SE.

| Site specific tag | site specific tag + [site-recommendation] | Questions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [stack-overflow](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) | [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow+site-recommendation) | 40 |
| [serverfault](/questions/tagged/serverfault) | [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serverfault+site-recommendation) | 7 |
| [superuser](/questions/tagged/superuser) | [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superuser+site-recommendation) | 10 |
| [mathoverflow](/questions/tagged/mathoverflow) | [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation+mathoverflow) | 2 |
| [ask-different](/questions/tagged/ask-different) | [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ask-different+site-recommendation) | 1 |
| [computer-science-se](/questions/tagged/computer-science-se) | [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-science-se+site-recommendation) | 4 |
| [software-engineering-se](/questions/tagged/software-engineering-se) | [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-engineering-se+site-recommendation) | 6 |
| [wordpress-se](/questions/tagged/wordpress-se) | [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-se+site-recommendation) | 3 |
| [math-se](/questions/tagged/math-se) | [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation+math-se) | 7 |
| [area-51](/questions/tagged/area-51) | [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/area-51+site-recommendation) | 26 |

So, in which cases does it make sense to include a site-specific tag?

---

##### Possible exceptions to the general tagging recommendation

I will list some exceptions. The Tags column doesn't include [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) because all the questions listed have this tag.

I started by reviewing questions tagged [wordpress.se](/questions/tagged/wordpress.se)

| Question | Tags | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [WordPress Answers or Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136577/289691) | [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion),[stack-overflow](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow),[questions](/questions/tagged/questions),[wordpress-se](/questions/tagged/wordpress-se) | Might require [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) |
| [Should I ask this question on WordPress Development or Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286143/289691) | [support](/questions/tagged/support),[wordpress.se](/questions/tagged/wordpress.se) | Might require [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) |
| [What is the intended difference between MathOverflow and Mathematics?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251476/289691) | [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion),[math.se](/questions/tagged/math.se),[mathoverflow](/questions/tagged/mathoverflow) | Might require [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) |

Sample of possible questions where the site-specific tag could be removed

| Question | Tags | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Where's the best place to get my iPad, iPhone and iPod touch questions answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54008/289691) | [ask-different](/questions/tagged/ask-different) |  |
| [WordPress questions - Where to ask now that we have Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58697/289691) | [wordpress.se](/questions/tagged/wordpress.se) |  |

---

The following come from comments on [Nij's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394121/289691).

1. Not all posts with [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) ask for a site recommendation.
2. Not all site recommendation questions have the appropriate mandatory tag, i.e., some should have [support](/questions/tagged/support) instead of [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).
3. Is it relevant if the site-specific tag was added because it's the answer or because it helps to connect with the site experts that might help to improve the answer recommending such a site or add a better answer?

---

Side note: It looks like some questions having [wordpress.se](/questions/tagged/wordpress.se) are because the questions mention WordPress, not because they are directly related to [WordPress development SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It never makes sense.

If you know the site already, the question isn't necessary. Adding a tag is in effect editing the question to include its answer, which is never necessary and interferes with the meaning of votes.

If you have to ask the question, the site tag is meta-tagging. There's a reason we delete those when they are added on main sites and reject suggestions when they're ideated on meta sites.

It's not a question about that site either, it's a question about the network as a whole. The fact that a site is the *answer* does not mean a site is the *question*.

Tags are for finding questions around a particular topic or focus. They're not shorthand for answers, or shortcuts for the system as a whole.

Consider the relatively common situation of a recommendation request that has multiple applicable sites. Which of them do you include? We don't have to find exceptions or resolve this if we just follow the plan: tags for questions, answers for answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nij. I don't feel comfortable with the first statement as I don't think that on Meta SE that will be taken as the community consensus. One of the rebuttals is that questions on Meta Stack Exchange rarely follow the Q&A model. On the other hand, using [tag:site-recommendation] is flexible. Not all questions having this tag are strictly site recommendation questions from users who don't know which sites exist. Several questions are asked to clarify the scope of 2 or more sites giving an intended question to be asked.

Comment: By the way, I don't understand the last part of the statement about *following the plan*, "answers for answers". Are you saying that tags should not be used to answer a question / as the answer of a question?

Comment: If tags were for answering, they'd be applied to answers to do so. If they're part of the question, they're not an answer.

Comment: Users incorrectly adding a site-recommendation tag when they are not seeking a site recommendation is the same as users incorrectly adding a discussion tag when they are not seeking discussion. Don't fix one wrong tag by making it two wrong tags.

Comment: I agree that tags should not be added as an answer, but tags are added to connect experts with questions. Someone might have added a site-specific tag like [tag:ask-different] to connect the question with experts on  Ask Different. This could be clarified in each specific case if the edit summary explains the reason for adding the tag. The site-specific experts might help to improve the answer or add a better answer.

Comment: @Rubén by that moment, the user is already gone and asked the question on ask different, based on the flawed recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

> It never makes sense. If you know the site already, the question isn't necessary. If you have to ask the question, the site tag is meta-tagging. It's also not a question about that site either, it's a question about the network as a whole.

--[Nij](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/341260/nij)

Tags should be used only taking into consideration the information *in the question*. That's the same reason we don't use tags about the (potential) solutions on a question that doesn't refer to the solution.

Comment: Could you extend this a bit? There are some posts about retagging based on the answers. Some mention that it should be done based on the accepted answer, but the problem with that is the one the OP decided, if they selected accept an answer, and there is not always a consensus about the correctness of such an answer. Some related posts: [Should we retag questions with topics proposed in the answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59333/289691), [Retagging questions with the answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35842/289691). I'm not sure that they are the best to be used as a reference

Comment: @Rubén and every single one of them is wrong. We tag questions, not answers, since the tags are for the consumption of the would be answerers. Also, that creates problems when there are multiple solutions to the same problem or later on there are more solutions, and everyone and their mother start adding tags.

Comment: I'm not wrong. There are indeed posts about retagging based on the answers. Here is another one [Should I retag a question with a tag that is based on the answer and not the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26913/289691)

Comment: @Rubén I'm referring to your "There are some posts about retagging based on the answers", not you being wrong.

Answer (score 1):

##### Specific Question retagging

###### Case 1

Regarding the specific case of the question having [ask-different](/questions/tagged/ask-different), this question was migrated from Super User, having [ipad](/questions/tagged/ipad)[iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) and [ask-different](/questions/tagged/ask-different) at that time. I removed these tags as they have a different usage on Meta Stack Exchange.

Despite the above being a single case, I think it might be fair to look at inbound migrated questions. It might be very likely that the site-specific tags were added before the question was migrated.

###### Case 2

[Could we possibly get a "featured program" section for profiles on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332217/289691)

The above question is a feature request, not a question asking for a site recommendation, not related to questions asking for a site recommendation or related to the tag. Probably, the user who added [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) thought that it should be used on posts *making a suggestion*.

###### Case 3

Questions with [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) + [google](/questions/tagged/google)

Questions with these tags are about where to ask questions about Google. [google](/questions/tagged/google) should be removed from them.

##### Case 4

[site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) + [wordpres-se](/questions/tagged/wordpres-se)

[wordpress-se](/questions/tagged/wordpress-se) should be removed from the following questions

| Question | Status Closed/Open | Status Tag Clean-Up |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [WordPress questions - Where to ask now that we have Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58697/289691) | Open | Pending |
| [WordPress Answers or Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136577/289691) | Open | Pending |
| [Should I ask this question on WordPress Development or Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286143/289691) | Open | Pending |

##### Case 5

[site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) + [area51](/questions/tagged/area51)

Most questions, including both tags, are because the answer recommended to make a new site proposal or to look at Area51 but some are not asking for a site recommendation; they might be criticizing something related to the site proposal process or another thing.

##### Thoughts

Some questions include site-specific tags because the question mentions a site. A possible typical case is OP's mentions looking for site recommendation because a question has been closed on, i.e., Computer Science SE, but the is not asking something about Computer Science SE. In cases like this, the site-specific tag should be removed because adding tags based on concepts mentioned in the question content is bad tagging, as tags should be added based on what is being asked, more specifically, the tags that better connect with the experts having the specific skills required to provide a specific answer to the question.